# What & where is net.sf.josql?

Tags: java, maven, activemq-classic

Look at this pom (as well as various other poms) in maven central:
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/activemq/activemq-optional/5.6.0/activemq-optional-5.6.0.pom.

In these poms are dependencies on net.sf.josql

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.josql</groupId> 
  <artifactId>josql</artifactId> 
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.josql</groupId> 
  <artifactId>gentlyweb-utils</artifactId> 
</dependency>
```

When you try http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.josql/josql, it would return a 404.

So ... why would maven central have a pom which includes a dependency that is not found in maven central?

In fact, I can't find net.sf.josql in either jboss or maven central repositories.

What is it and where can I find it?

Comment: net/sf/josql would be the path

Comment: There could be any number of reasons why it's not in central, most likely being that the developer of the dependency hosts their own repo and doesn't want to keep it in two places, where as the person who created the artifact you want to use doesn't have their own repo. Googling net.sf.josql gave me a repo as the top link.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Guide to uploading artifacts to the Central Repository](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-central-repository-upload.html#FAQ_and_common_mistakes):

> **I have other repositories or pluginRepositories listed in my POM, is that a problem?**
>
> At present, this won't preclude your project from being included, but we do strongly encourage making sure all your dependencies are included in Central. If you rely on sketchy repositories that have junk in them or disappear, it just creates havok for downstream users. Try to keep your dependencies among reliable repos like Central, Jboss, etc.

So clearly Apache wished people would do this, but they don't thoroughly enforce it.

Googling for your artifact, it seems it is hosted here: http://repo.fusesource.com/maven2/. You will need to add this as an additional repository in your POM or settings file (see http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-repositories.html for the runes).

Comment: I trust maven central and jboss repositories (somewhat). I mean, if  either of these two repos go down - it would be a bad (but tolerable) day. But can I trust fusesource availability - Will its organisation one day go bankrupt and its repo service disappear from maven-scape altogether?

Comment: I completely agree, it's far from ideal. It's an open source project, maybe you can kick start the move to Maven central...

Comment: ActviveMQ 5.7 uses JARs from central only now.

Comment: I am marking this as the answer due to combination of Duncan Jone's answer and Claus Ibsen's comment.

Answer (score 3):

```
<repository>
  <id>repo.fusesource.com</id>
  <name>repo.fusesource.com</name>
  <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/maven2-legacy/</url>
  <layout>default</layout>
</repository>
```

Please add this on you pom.xml

Answer (score 1):

I had same isse with Apollo 1.7.1.
I found all dependencies in apache-apollo-1.7.1-windows-distro.zip (apache-apollo-1.7.1\lib folder).

So I just run folowing in apache-apollo-1.7.1\lib

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=proton-0.3.0-fuse-2.jar -DgroupId=org.apache.qpid -DartifactId=proton-hawtdispatch -Dversion=0.3.0-fuse-2 -Dpackaging=jar
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=josql-1.5.jar -DgroupId=net.sf.josql -DartifactId=josql -Dversion=1.5 -Dpackaging=jar
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=gentlyweb-utils-1.5.jar -DgroupId=net.sf.josql -DartifactId=gentlyweb-utils -Dversion=1.5 -Dpackaging=jar
```